# Algorithm to create random, but valid mathematical expressions

Tags: python, algorithm, arithmetic-expressions

In order generate large test data for an expression parser *(based on Dijkstra's shunting yard)*, I came up with following *Python script*:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ast
import sys
import random
import operator as op

def gen_digit(n):

    i = 0
    digit = ""

    if random.randint(0, 1e06) % 17 == 0:
        digit = digit + "-"

    while i < n:
        if i == 0:
            digit = digit + str(random.randint(1, 9))
        else:
            digit = digit + str(random.randint(0, 9))

        i = i + 1

    return digit;

def rnd_op():
    ops = [ "+", "-", "*", "/", "%" ]
    return ops[random.randint(0, 4)]

operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
        ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.Mod: op.mod, ast.USub: op.neg}

def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num):
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand))
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)

def eval_expr(expr):
    return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)

def right_op(op, expr):

    if op == "/" or op == "%":

        try:
            v = eval_expr(expr)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            v = 0

        if v == 0:
            return op + " (" + expr + " + " + gen_digit(random.randint(1, 4)) + ")"
        else:
            return op + " " + expr

    else:
        return op + " " + expr

def gen_term():

    term = ""

    if random.randint(0, 1e06) % 17 == 0:
        term += "-"

    term += "(" + right_op(gen_digit(random.randint(1, 4)), \
            right_op(rnd_op() + " " + gen_digit(random.randint(1, 4)), \
            rnd_op() + " " + gen_digit(random.randint(1, 4)))) + ")"

    return term

def build_expr():
    return "(" + gen_term() + " " + \
        right_op(rnd_op(), gen_term()) + " " + \
        right_op(rnd_op(), gen_term()) + ")"

def rnd_expr(expr, m, d):

    if d < m:
        expr = "(" + build_expr() + " " + \
                right_op(rnd_op(), rnd_expr(expr, m, d + 1)) + " " + \
                right_op(rnd_op(), build_expr()) + ")"

    return expr

argc = len(sys.argv)

if argc > 1:

    dpth = int(sys.argv[1]);
    sys.setrecursionlimit(dpth * 10)
    print (rnd_expr(build_expr(), dpth, 0))

else:
    print (rnd_expr(build_expr(), 1, 0))
```

My *shunting yard implementation* (another `C++` project) is correct and accepts the four basic arithmetic operators plus *% (modulo)*.

I want to get the generated expression to be valid, but currently I encounter sometimes *division/modulo by zero errors*, despite I tried to avaoid them. Further the `ast` overflows on a recursion depth greater than `98`.

**Edit:** the *division/modulo by zero errors* occur not within the *Python script*, but by parsing with an external tool like `bc` on *Linux*.

Does somebody has an idea, why the function `right_op` or the *algorithm* in general fails sometimes.

Comment: I tried it 1000 times with argument 50 but didn't get the division by zero error (python 3.5.1 on widows 7). maybe you could provide a random.seed to reproduce the error.

Comment: The division by zero can get detected via an external tool like `bc` (an command line calculator for *Linux*). I will not that into the question.

Comment: I can use a tool from the main project, which gives an exit code of 1 if the expression is wrong and so I tested it in a *bash* shell with: `while(./rnd_expr.py 40 | expr2cf); do true; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the the *Python script* is doing what it is dedicated to do: to generate valid test data!

If you change

```
def rnd_op():
    ops = [ "+", "-", "*", "/", "%" ]
    return ops[random.randint(0, 4)]
```

to

```
def rnd_op():
    ops = [ "+", "-", "*", "/", "%" ]
    return ops[random.randint(0, 3)]
```

i.e. to omit creation of the *modulo operator `%`*, than following **one-liner** in a `bash` shell will prove it correct:

`while(./rnd_expr.py 4 | perl -e 'my $exp = <STDIN>; if(!defined(eval($exp))) { print $@." ".$exp; exit(1) } else { print eval($exp)."\n"; exit(0); }' ); do true; done`

while *without the change* it will complain about *modulo by zero*. Rechecking with `bc` show the same result.

My main `C++` project mostly accepts the expressions, while `perl` and `bc` both mostly always reject it.
So I have a (probably) precedence error in my main `C++` project.

**Edit:** **both** are correct, `perl/bc` and *my main `C++` project*. The first are interpreting the result as `integer` and truncating the intermediate result, while my main `C++` project is calculating *symbolic (i.e. with a fraction class)*.

**Another proof, that *rubberduck debugging* is actually working :)**